# how to get the STL list which is stored in a STL array?

Tags: c++, arrays, list, stl

I'm trying making a hash table with STL array and list . In my header file 
it's defined that

```
              typedef std::list<Bike*> BikePtrList;
```

and 2 classes :

```
class BikeHashTableADT : public std::array< BikePtrList, 256 >
class BikeHashTableIMP : public BikeHashTableADT
```

I'd like to store " `Bike*` " in the list , and store the lists in an array.
What I do in cpp file is call this function

```
void BikeHashTableIMP::addBikePtr(Bike* ptr)
{
    int hashInt = hashFun(ubptr->license); // integer returned from hash function 

    BikePtrList &tmp=(*this)[hashInt];  // "this" means the class BikeHashTableIMP
    std::list<Bike*> tmp.push_back(ptr);
    (*this)[hashInt]=tmp;            

}
```

There is a run-time error and every time this function is called and new **Bike* ptr** is push_back to the list , the prior data stored in the list is covered.
Could anyone tell me what's wrong with my code ?

Comment: "I'm trying making a hash table with STL array and list " Is there some reason you couldn't just use [a hash table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)?

Comment: Why are you deriving from a `std::array`? What's wrong with just having a member of that type?

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE] please.

Comment: The collection types in the standard library are not made to be inherited from.

Comment: That looks like a convoluted way of writing `(*this)[hashInt].push_back(ptr);`, but there's nothing obviously wrong with it (beyond the syntax error). The ultimate cause is probably somewhere else, in the surrounding code. The primary suspect would be your hashing function, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
std::list<Bike*> tmp.push_back(ptr);
```

Is wierd. The std::list doesn't belong there. Did you mean to just write

```
tmp.push_back(ptr);
```

?

And the line

```
(*this)[hashInt]=tmp;
```

also appears to be unneeded. tmp is already the same as (*this)[hashInt].

Comment: I try   " tmp.push_back(ptr);"   and remove the line "(*this)[hashInt]=tmp; "
but there's a run-time error...and the result was still wrong...

Comment: If push_back fails, it means that the list is invalid. How do you initialize the BikeHashTableIMP instance?